# Copy specific sequences from a multifasta file a number of times as defined by a table

Tags: awk, grep, fasta

I have a multi fasta file that looks like this:

```
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
...
```

I have a second file with the sequence names and a number next to it, looking like this:

```
sequence_1 3
sequence_2 5
...
```

I would like to copy the sequences in the fasta file a number of times as defined by the second column in the second file, in order to get the following output:

```
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
...
```

Does anyone have a solution with grep or AWK (or any other unix commands) for this? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I try to avoid making data sets bigger whenever possible, could you possibly just annotate the defline of your fasta file with the copy number and let whatever consumes your resulting file deal with it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A truly ugly but working solution:

```
awk -F' ' '{ for(i=1; i<$2;i++) print $1}' names.txt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I '{}' grep -A 1 {} seq.fasta
```

- The first `awk` statement splits the file with names and repeats and prints it multiple times
- The second `awk` statment prints each line (`grep` ignores identical patterns, workaround for this particular "feature" of `grep`)
- Next we use `xargs` to pass the lines to `grep`

Output:

> ```
> >sequence_1
> MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
> >sequence_1
> MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
> >sequence_2
> SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
> >sequence_2
> SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
> >sequence_2
> SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
> >sequence_2
> SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
> ```

For large files it is should surely not the most performant solution to call `grep` multiple times instead of repeating the output.

Answer (score 0):

If your sequence allways has one line:

```
$ cat sequence.fasta 
sequence_1 3
sequence_2 5

$ cat file.fasta 
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL

$ awk 'NR==FNR{s[">"$1]=$2;next}
       $1 in s{getline fasta
             for (i=1;i<=s[$1];i++){
               print $1
               print fasta
               }
     }' sequence.fasta file.fasta
```

**Result**

```
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_1
MTAGAAAPSATGSDAAAELSELYR
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
>sequence_2
SAPDEPVAVVGLACRLPGAADPEAFWALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I also found a way (very simple, actually) to do it with R. I'm posting it here in case someone is interested:
First, you have to read the fasta file into R with readAAStringSet function from Biostrings package and the table file with read.delim function. Then use the function rep to do the job:

```
    fastafile <- readAAStringSet("file.fasta")
    secondfile <- read.delim("second.file", header=F, sep=" ")
    multiply <- rep(fastafile, secondfile$V2)
```